# Sikuli is not working in some machine

Tags: ui-automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I have tried Sikuli for ui-automation.  I have created an image and i tried to perform a click operation. It is working in one PC but while trying in another PC it is not working.  I am getting an error "Fail can not find P(c:/users/--/pictures/googles.png".  What might be the cause for the issue.  Should I change any settings in my machine.  Can u please help me.

Thanks,
Ganesh. K

Comment: What do you mean trying on another pc? It sounds like you interrogated an application on one machine, and tried running the automation test on another without copying the png file of the control you are trying to click (which sikuli uses to find the control on the screen)

Comment: Have a look here: http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2016/05/transferring-sikuli-scripts-to-another.html

Comment: The application is working in one machine.  But the same application (Not integration the same code) is not working in another machine.  I have the image in the folder.

Comment: I got an answer that to set Settings.MinSimilarity. But I dont have Settings option in Sikuli4Net. Do you have any knowledge on that should I add any package.??

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to the directory. For example, try changing the "/" for "\\". The directory should look something like this:

```
"C:\\users\\my_directory\\file.png"
```

Another reason could be that your actual user doesn't have the rights to see that folder. Try putting that images in another directory outside the specific folder user.

Comment: I got an answer that to set Settings.MinSimilarity.  But I dont have Settings option in Sikuli4Net.  Do you have any knowledge on that should I add any  package.??